# Send a large collection of object to WCF service

Tags: wcf

My client WPF application which reads a big CSV file and creates list of object based on data. Records is almost 40,000 so list of object is 40,000. Now, I tried to send these collection but not able to send to Wcf service though i changed binding attributes of web.config and app.config file. I tried to debug wcf code but nothing happens i.e no exception or control does not move to debug point. For example:

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRulesEngineManagementService"
              maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
              maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
              transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                    maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
```

I searched in google but did not find solution. I am totally stuck. How can i solve this issue? Any kind of hints/idea/ code sample is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your complete web.config.

Typical mistake with settings binding configuration is that you won't set it to your service elements
with bindingConfiguration attribute.
sou you have to have something like this

```
<service ... >
<endpoint ....  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRulesEngineManagementService" .... >

</service>
```

If you don't get any exception or even hit a breakpoint that means your service fail before your code was executed at WCF/IIS side

Please set these config to your web.config so you can see a error on this side.

in your system.serviceModel section

```
<system.serviceModel>
...
    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="3000" />
    </diagnostics>     
....
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and add new element system.diagnostics. It will save your log to c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="XmlSerialization.Compilation" value="4"/>
  </switches>
   <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="xml" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\temp\WCFLoging.svclog" />
    </sharedListeners>
  </system.diagnostics>
```